# an unhandled exception is occured in myproject.vshost.exe

Tags: c#, unhandled-exception

I am creating a windows application using 3rd party dll. They had given some predefined methods to use. There is a method `SetTag()` which is use to update a value. Now my work is to get data from tcp client and send to this method. My tcp part is working well, I had tested it. The problem is occurring at the time when I call `SetTag()`. It works well for a while but after some time, it's showing just-in-time debugger pop-up with exception

> An unhandled exception has occurred in myproject.vshost.exe

I don't understand from where this exception is occurring.

Whenever I get data from tcp client, my `UpdateValues()` is called, which calls the third-party `SetTag()`

```
// valuesInArray is an object array which contain
// the data from tcp client after converted to object
UpdateValues(valuesInArray);
```

and the method:

```
public void UpdateValues(object[] values)
{
    this.BeginUpdate();
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        this.SetTag(TagHandle[i], (values[i]), Quality.Good, FileTime.UtcNow);
    }
    this.EndUpdate(false);
}
```

I had created a simulator, where the data is not coming from tcp client, itis sending data in a timer tick event. In that case no error is occurring and the program runs smoothly. Can you suggest why this error is occurring using tcp client and how I get rid of it?

Comment: How about surrounding SetTag(...) with a try catch and investigating stacktrace and inner exception of the "unhandled" exception when it occurs? [Debug tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/sc65sadd.aspx)

Comment: What is the declaration of SetTag in your c# code? Are the parameters correct as expected?

Comment: try catch is not catching any error. how to see stacktrace?

Comment: @stamhaney: yes sir,this method is provided by the vendor.

Comment: Subscribe to AppDomain.Current.DomainUnhandledException to understand what happends.

Comment: Why dont you enable all exceptions in VS and see where are you getting the exception?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough details to explain what the error is. However, your code will benefit from using a `try {} catch {}` to 'handle' the exception. The exception has the details you are looking for.

public void UpdateValues(

```
object[] values)
{
    this.BeginUpdate();
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            this.SetTag(TagHandle[i], (values[i]), Quality.Good, FileTime.UtcNow);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Log or print out the details
            Console.WriteLine("Error occurred setting the value.");
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
    this.EndUpdate(false);
}
```

In this example, the exception message and stack trace are printed to the console. Look in this output for the cause of your exception.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 4 and later, you need to mark the containing method (`UpdateValues`) with `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute` and `SecurityCriticalAttribute` to catch some special exceptions such as `AccessViolationException`